# Comparing two strings and count differences with Stream API

Tags: string, java-8, functional-programming, string-comparison

Today I was trying to compare two strings with Stream API in java. 
Let's assume that we have two Strings:

```
String str1 = "ABCDEFG"
String str2 = "ABCDEEG"
```

We can make streams from it with:

```
str1.chars().stream()...
str2.chars().stream()...
```

And now I want to compare these string, char by char and iterate some variable when char will be different on the same position, so the result in this case will be 1, because there is one difference in this.

I was trying to do call map or forEach from first and there my journey ends, because I don't know how to get corresponding element form second stream.

Comment: Streams are not to be used as loops. Loops are made for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that both the strings are of same length(integer max), you can count the differences as :

```
int diffCount = (int) IntStream.range(0, str1.length())
                         .filter(i -> str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) // corresponding characters from both the strings
                         .count();
```

Comment: By the way, `var` was introduced in [tag:java-10], hence avoiding its usage according to the tags of the question.

Comment: now that you have mentioned it, how would you do it using java10's `var`? can you please append that to your answer?

Comment: @Kartik nothing much different than using `var <variableName>` in a local construct. The comment was to highlight the usage in the question, which now has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both String are of same length, you can use this way too.

```
        long count = IntStream.iterate(0, n-> n+1)
            .limit(str1.length()).filter(i -> str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)).count();
```